# How does one find if the following series converges: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\cos\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\cos\frac{π}{n}\right)$$

Its limit is $0$ so the necessary condition is verified. Now I don't know how to check whether it converges or not

Comment: Your indices are inconsistent; I assume you want them both to be $n$. Anyway, $\pi/n$ is small when $n$ is large, so approximate $\cos(x)$ near $x=0$ and plug in $x=\pi/n$. A bit more precisely, since your terms are positive, you want an upper bound on $1-\cos(\pi/n)$ which amounts to a lower bound on $\cos(\pi/n)$.

Comment: Would it help you if you knew that $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$?

Comment: How do we know that $1-cos\dfrac{\pi}{n} = 2sin^2\dfrac{π}{2n}$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$0\le1-\cos\frac{\pi}{n}=2\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n}\le2\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)^2=\frac{\left(\frac{\pi^2}{2}\right)}{n^2}$$

Note that $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, and you have that your sum also does.

Comment: How do we know that $1-cos\dfrac{\pi}{n} = 2sin^2 \dfrac{π}{2n}$ ?

Comment: Write $cos(2x) = \cos(x+x) = cos(x)^2 - sin(x)^2 = 1 - 2 sin(x)^2$, rearrange and plug in $\pi/2n$ for $x$.

Comment: @ArthurSinulis that's it - thanks. Can also use $1-\cos x = \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\cos x}$ to establish a slightly weaker bound if you'd rather keep it simpler.